# Problem with Twitter package by sixohsix

Tags: python, ubuntu, twitter

I am using a Twitter Python package which is installed by

```
easy_install twitter
```

The package can be found at : https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

I am running into some weird errors.

```
import twitter

twitter_search = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com")
results = twitter_search.search(q="japan")
```

Than I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twitter-1.6-py2.6.egg/twitter/api.py", line 150, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twitter-1.6-py2.6.egg/twitter/api.py", line 165, in _handle_response
    raise TwitterHTTPError(e, uri, self.format, arg_data)
twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1/search.json using parameters: (q=japan)
details: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { background-color: #fff; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; }
            h1 { margin: 10px 0; }
            img { border: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/"><img src="/images/search/twitter-logo-large.png"></a>
        <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
        <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

May I know what am I doing wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6, and using twitter-1.6

Comment: Which Twitter Python bindings?

Comment: Probably a bug, maybe report it here https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a library defect that the author *just* [fixed](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter/commit/652c5402f2c931dd91af107b4419f69541f78ca3).

The problem was that the library was versioning the path to the *[search](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/search)* resource, and thereby causing a 404 error.

This part of the error message you provided details the problem:

```
Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1/search.json using parameters: (q=japan)
```

This tells us that the URL the library was trying to access was:

http://search.twitter.com/1/search.json?q=japan

Instead, it should have assembled this URL:

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=japan

So, if you get the latest version of the library, I think that will solve your issue.